# Is there any way to create report data from google analytics in angular?

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-data-api

i used to options and failed in angular
first case :I try used GA4 to get data but not work

> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runRealtimeReport

and return

```
error :
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this property. To learn more about Property ID, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/property-id.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

and this, error because the authentication and failed in angular

second case: I used Analytic Firesbase in angular
[Getting started with Google Analytics](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/HEAD/docs/analytics/getting-started.md)
but not found the method to get data from analytic

Answer (score 0):

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this property

Means that the user you are currently logging in and authenticating with does not have permission to access the Google Analytics account you are trying to access.  In the event you are using a service account then you need to take the service account email address and go to the admin section of Google analytics website and add the service account as a user granting it permission to access the data.

This video will explain the issue in more detail and show you how to fix it. [User doesn't have any google analytics accounts easy solution](https://youtu.be/s0fwl7tbS8U)